# Некрасивое отображение значения в TDBEditEh при использовании маски

Tags: delphi, firebird, interbase, компоненты

У меня в БД Firebird в таблице есть поле с типом «NUMERIC(9,1)».
Мне нужно, чтоб в приложении пользователь не мог ввести больше двух цифр в целой части и 1 в дробной.
Для этого я использую компонент «TDBEditEh», т.к. в нем есть свойство «EditMask», которое я поставил в значение «99,9;_»

Все бы ничего, но при установки курсора в окошко «TDBEditEh», выглядет не очень красиво, отображается значение см. рис. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может можно как-нибудь поправить? Т.е. чтоб "8" не съезжала влево и не выглядела как "8_".
Честно говоря думал что свойство http://www.ehlib.com/online-help/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=index.html может поправить ситуацию – но не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить с обычным TEdit вот такое решение:

Исправил, возможно не самое элегантное решение, но полностью соответствует вашим условиям

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //устанавливаем курсор в конец
  Edit1.SelStart := Length( Edit1.Text );
  Edit1.SelLength := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  //проверяем, если забыли ввести разделитель, то вводим сами
  if not(Key in [#8]) then
    if Length(Edit1.Text) = 2 then
      begin
        if not(Edit1.Text[2] = ',') then
          begin
            Edit1.Text:= Edit1.Text + ',';
            Edit1.MaxLength:= Length(Edit1.Text) + 1;
            //устанавливаем курсор в конец
            Edit1.SelStart := Length( Edit1.Text );
            Edit1.SelLength := 0;
          end;
      end;

  case Key of
    #8,'0'..'9' :  ; // цифры и <BackSpace>
    ',': // разделитель целой и дробной частей числа
      begin
        Edit1.MaxLength:= Length(Edit1.Text) + 2; // устанавливаем максимальное количество символов
        if Pos(',',(Sender as TEdit).Text) <> 0 then
          Key := #0; // запрет ввода второго разделителя
      end;
  else
    key:= #0;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  //устанавливаем курсор в конец
  Edit1.SelStart := Length( Edit1.Text );
  Edit1.SelLength := 0;
end;
```

Comment: идея хорошая, только немного доработать, т.к. тут можно вводить сотые. (например: вводишь 65,8 потом удаляешь "5", и после "8" можно еще дописывать цифры)

Comment: Не вижу преград, постоянно держать курсор в конце